# Ridiculously simple logic still gives error

Tags: c++

I have two chars.
Each of them stores digits between 0  and 9.
I want to find the sum of these two and then modulo 10 to ensure the result in a single digit (0-9)
And finally convert the result back to char.

I did this but it won't work:

```
char a = '4';
char b = '8';
char c = (char)((a - '0') + (b - '0') % 10);
```

Comment: You forgot to switch back from numeric value to ASCII value

Comment: What do you mean? That's why I have char typecast.

Comment: Typecast will not magically turn `4` into `'4'`.

Comment: @Bazooka typecast doesn't help, you probably need to add `'0'` again.

Comment: `char c = ((a - '0') + (b - '0')) % 10 + '0';`

Answer (score 3):

The line

`char c = (char)((a - '0') + (b - '0') % 10);`

Performs

`char c = (char)(4 + 8 % 10)`

But modulus operator comes [before](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the addition operator...

You get `char c = char(12)`, equivalent to a [new page](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You may also want to add a `'0'` to c, although due to the current order of operations you have, will NOT give you a 0-9 number.

Comment: Even if I put an extra bracked as: `char c = (char)(((a - '0') + (b - '0')) % 10);`, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: @Bazooka then you are doing `char c = (char)2;` which is another ascii control character. See the last sentence of Don's answer